# How to properly create Kubernetes resource in Azure DevOps environment with REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create Kubernetes resource(generic provider) in Azure DevOps portal with Rest api, but without any success. On the other end I have properly created Kubernetes service connection that I would like to connect with that resource. When I do it manually in portal, it works fine.
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/kubernetes/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-7.2#kubernetesresource

First thing that bothers me, is that I don't see how can I pass parameters as server url or secret. When creating only with basic parameters from body - I only get: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Rhj.png)

Has anybody faced something similar ? Or any advice ? Thank you in advance.
Here is the code:

```
$body = @{
clusterName       = $clusterName
name              = $resourceName
namespace         = $namespace
serviceEndpointId = $serviceConnectionId
} | ConvertTo-Json\`your text

$headers = @{
Authorization  = "Basic " + \[Convert\]::ToBase64String(\[Text.Encoding\]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
"Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$createNewResourceUri = "<https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/environments/$environmentId/providers/kubernetes?api-version=7.2-preview.2>"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $createNewResourceUri -Headers $headers -Method POST -Body $body
```

I have tried several possible body options, checked web inspector for API when manual crating, but I could not make it work.

More info:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVTlW.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAEcD.png

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Based on your update, I believe the option to `Accept untrusted certificates` is the key to resolve the issue, since I could reproduce the same issue if I referenced the K8S service connection that was manually created with `Service Account` via web UI.
[image]

For this, I tested to create the K8S service connection with the following API request and managed to resolve the issue.

```
#The values of $apiToken and $serviceAccountCertificate can be found in the service account secret (in the output of this command kubectl get secret <service-account-secret-name> -n <namespace> -o json) 
$apiToken = "xxxx"
$serviceAccountCertificate = "xxxx"
$serverURL = "https://azxxxxcluster-dns-apnq1tbs.hcp.southeastasia.azmk8s.io:443"

$organization = "ADOOrgName"
$project = "TheProjectName"
$MyPat = 'xxxxxxxx'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$URL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?&api-version=7.1-preview.4"

$header = @{
'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat
'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$body = @{
    data = @{
        authorizationType = "ServiceAccount"
        acceptUntrustedCerts = $true
    }
    name = "AKSSvcCnn-frameworks"
    type = "kubernetes"
    url = $serverURL
    authorization = @{
        scheme = "Token"
        parameters = @{
            apiToken = $apiToken
            serviceAccountCertificate = $serviceAccountCertificate
            isCreatedFromSecretYaml = $false
        }
    }
    serviceEndpointProjectReferences = @(
        @{
            name = "AKSSvcCnn-frameworks"
            projectReference = @{
                id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
    )
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Headers $header -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5)
```

In the request below to add new K8S resource , reference the id of the new service connection above.

[image]

### Legacy

The reason we need to input `server URL` and `service account secret` when adding K8S resource via web UI is that this operation basically includes 2 steps.

- Step 1: It will create a new K8S service connection with the input parameters;
  [image]
- Step 2: Add the K8S resource into environment referencing the K8S service connection(`serviceConnectionId`) established in `Step 1`.

Please check if you have already created a valid K8S service connection authenticating against service account and secret. If yes, we can proceed to call in the mentioned API request of step 2 without using those two parameters. Here is my script for a reference.

```
$clusterName = "azxxxxcluster"
$resourceName = "dev"
$namespace = "dev"
$serviceConnectionId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$organization = "ADOOrgName"
$project = "TheProjectName"
$environmentId = 44
$MyPat = 'xxxxxxxx'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$body = @{
    clusterName       = $clusterName
    name              = $resourceName
    namespace         = $namespace
    serviceEndpointId = $serviceConnectionId
}
$headers = @{
    'Authorization'  = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}
$createNewResourceUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/environments/$environmentId/providers/kubernetes?api-version=7.2-preview.2"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $createNewResourceUri -Headers $headers -Method POST -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json)
```

If the service connection is valid, the K8S resource is automatically validated as soon as it is added in the environment.
[image]

Hope the information helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and effort :) The idea, that I don't need to pass fqdn and secret and just reference to service connection, which already has that sounds good. But unfortunately I am able to create the resource as before but still get message 'Unable to connect to the cluster and namespace chosen for this resource.' I followed the steps and I am sure that service account is 100% correctly configured (we are already using it for connecting to cluster). So that makes even more confused of what could be the issue.

Comment: Hi there, This API works for me to add K8S request. There could be differences in how our referenced K8S service connections were created.  Was your service connection with the service connection ID of `$serviceConnectionId` generated against `service account` like that in my answer? Can you please specify your steps with some screenshots? I will try and reproduce it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly the same. The difference is that I am creating that service connection (authenticated with service account - per namespace) with Terraform. The service connection has then same config as you wrote and as I wrote its working fine with cluster related namespace. I tried to create that Kubernetes resource manually - I get desired outcome ONLY when checked 'Accept untrusted certificates' - otherwise I get same result as with api call. Does that makes any difference ?

Comment: I also added some screens to main issue - its my 1st time here - so might not the best way  :)

Comment: Hi @JurajNovotný, Sorry for the late response as I was pretty occupied this week. I have updated the answer based on our phrased findings. That works to resolve the issue from my side. Please pay attention to the `projectReference.Id` in the updated request to create a valid K8S service connection. Hope this helps. Cheers.